# Bootstrap 3 - Image & text in list of same height , but for mobile, text should wrap image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help to display a list with data just like in the screen-shot below. On desktop and tablet I need the image to the left and text to the right side with same height in `ul > li` regardless of the height of the text. But on mobile deceives, the text should wrap around the image, so that the image can be still on the left side and text should be wrapping around it.
Thanks!

[image: Image of Layout]

Comment: Where is your code? Have you even tried anything?

Comment: None of your questions include ANY code. You are expected to provide a [minimal and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order for us to assist you. This is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  display: table;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.Ltcol {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .col {
    display: block;
  }
}

.col-container ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Responsive Equal Height Columns</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the result. </p>

<div class="col-container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="col Ltcol" style="background:#eee">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Image</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col" style="background:#ddd">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="col Ltcol" style="background:#eee">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Image</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col" style="background:#ddd">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="col Ltcol" style="background:#eee">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Image</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col" style="background:#ddd">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Hi guys, managed to get it worked with code below: (Please change browser size to display its effects)